# Remove parameter on page with gridview connected to dropdown selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0, drop-down-menu

I have a simple ASP.NET/C# page with a DropDownList ("Category") and a GridView ("Items"). Each pull data via SqlDataSource from their respective tables. The "Items" data source has a ControlParameter for the Select statement and the dropdown automatically posts back. Everything works fine -- I can select an item in the dropdown list and the gridview automatically changes like I expect.

Is there a way (within ASP.NET) that I can have a "show all" item in the dropdown list that will remove the parameter from the datasource so it will pull in all items regardless of Category? Or is that not possible and I'd need to switch some of this over to the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on `Category`:

A) If `Category` is a varchar type, then you should be able to modify your `Select` of the `SqlDataSource` to be as:

```
... WHERE Category LIKE @Category
```

and include in your `DropDownList` an item:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="(Any)" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
```

B) If  `Category` is a numeric type, then you should be able to modify your `Select` to check for a "magic number" (a number that you reserve via a business rule to mean a wildcard -- and make sure to have documented somewhere):

```
... WHERE Category = @Category OR @Category = -99
```

and include in your `DropDownList` an item:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="(Any)" Value="-99"></asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

If the Category is a numeric (datavaluefield) then you can follow as below..add a new item

```
<asp:ListItem Text="(Any)" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
```

in your select statement's filterexpression you need to write something like

```
Convert(Category,System.String) like '{0}%'
```

This will change your numeric column to String type and your filter expression will pass the correct parameter

If its a String type then there is no need to use Convert function.

```
<asp:ListItem Text="(Any)" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>

Category like '{0}%'
```

let me know if this helps for you.